Getting JWT Token fails in .Net code ported from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 8.0
I have some old code written for .NET 4.7.2 using WebRequest.Create(..) to get the JWT Token from a server and this works as expected in .NET 4.7.2.
When I port the code (which is a console app) straight to .NET 8.0 - created a new .NET 8.0 console and copied the code across and run it - it fails with a "http 401 Unauthorized" error.
When I look at the HTTP messages sent over the wire using Fiddler I can see the code is sending exactly the same message, and in fact what is produced is a http 401 response followed by the successful 200 response - this happens for both version of the code.
For some reason the .NET 8.0 code does not handle the 401 and throws an exception even though the valid token is returned in the subsequent 200 response.
Any ideas what I need to set in the .NET 8.0 code to get this to work?

What authentication is in use? I assume that the 401 prompts a subsequent request with additional authentication/authorization that WebRequest just handles. Could you include the requests and responses from Fiddler in the question?

Ahhh, wasn't there a breaking change in 8 concerning JWT? => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events could that be relevant? Hard to tell without some code *wink, wink

Its; default credentials for the user (corp network backed by AD), the request & response in Fiddler are exactly the same for 4.7.2 and 8.0 versions,# it's something in the stack that is not handling the 401 Unauthorized
